# What's the difference between the function of draw tube, coarse adjustment screws and fine adjustment screws?

Tags: microscopy

I am having trouble with taking in the particular functions of draw tube, coarse and fine adjustment screws.

The book that I read says:

1. The **Draw tube** can be drawn up or down to focus the image.
2. The **coarse adjustment screws** are used for focusing the objects to view them clearly.
3. The **fine adjustment screws** are used to sharpen the focus.

The functions of these parts look similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their functions are identical. however, the three mechanisms have different sensitivities. the draw tube knob moves the eyepiece assembly a large distance for a given amount of rotation of the knob, hence allowing quick and convenient movement to an approximate focus. the coarse adjustment screw moves the eyepiece assembly a smaller distance for a given amount of rotation, allowing a better approximation of the correct focus. the fine adjustment screw moves the eyepiece assembly only a very tiny distance for a given amount of screw rotation, hence allowing very precise positioning of the assembly for sharpest focus.

it would be a tiring and tedious job to work a focusing mechanism with only a fine adjustment screw. similarly, it would be very hard to zero in on sharp focus with only a drawtube knob.